# enlarge the spacing after subcaption (subcaption package)

Tags: captions, subcaption

When I use the `subcaption` package, there is but a very small amount of whitespace between the subcaption title and the image below it.

I can add a big space with '\bigskip', but I want to know whether there is a command to change the amount of spacing globally.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[font={small}, justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage[labelformat=simple]{subcaption}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\alph{subfigure})}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{position=below,skip=25pt}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[!htbp]
\subcaptionbox{heading}{\includegraphics[width=0.49\linewidth]{imagefile}}%
\hfill
\subcaptionbox{heading}{\includegraphics[width=0.49\linewidth]{imagefile}}

\subcaptionbox{heading}{\includegraphics[width=0.49\linewidth]{imagefile}}%
\hfill
\subcaptionbox{heading}{\includegraphics[width=0.49\linewidth]{imagefile}}

\caption{text text text text text text text text text text text text text} 
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The instruction `\captionsetup[subfigure]{position=below,skip=25pt}` tells LaTeX to insert 25pt of whitespace between the subfigure's image and associated caption. That would appear to be quite a lot -- likely even excessive. You probably want something like `\captionsetup[subfigure]{position=below,skip=0.5\baselineskip}` -- *and* set the `\belowcaptionskip` length parameter, as shown in [@Zxcvasdf's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/652002/5001).

Comment: Thank you. @Mico

Comment: @zongxian, please accept the answer if it answers your question so that others get to know it has been addressed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `\belowcaptionskip`.

```tex
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[font={small}, justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage[labelformat=simple]{subcaption}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\alph{subfigure})}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{position=below,skip=1em}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
    \setlength\belowcaptionskip{1em}
    
    \blindtext[1]
    \begin{figure}[!htbp]
        \subcaptionbox{heading}{\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{imagefile}}
        \subcaptionbox{heading}{\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{imagefile}}\\
        \subcaptionbox{heading}{\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{imagefile}}
        \subcaptionbox{heading}{\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{imagefile}}
        \caption{text text text text text text text text text text text text text} 
    \end{figure}
    
    \blindtext[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]